# Show .idea folder in PhpStorm project tool window

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

PhpStorm hides the .idea folder in the project tool window by default. However, I'd like to show it in order to inspect the files and add/edit a .idea/.gitignore file to include and exclude specific files from version control. I have searched for project configuration options in order to unhide the .idea folder, but haven't found a way.

I could just use another editor to manage the files in the .idea folder, but I'd like to use the git-integration of PhpStorm to manage these files.

Comment: There shouldn't be a .gitignore in the .idea/ folder. You should just add it to the .gitignore file in your project root and set exclusions there. The .idea folder is just for PhpStorm internals/settings. You can ignore the idea folder, but set exclusions for some files you would want to commit/track (e.g. if you want your code style rules to apply for all devs in your team, just exclude the code style settings file from being ignored and it will commit).

Comment: Well .. there is special option to show `.idea` folder in a Project View panel .. but as @Oldskool already said -- there is *absolutely no need* for that in your case -- you should manage such exclusions via `.gitignore` file in a project root.

Comment: As you suggest, I will use a .gitignore file in the project root. It's still helpful for me to inspect the contents of the files in the .idea folder directly in PhpStorm. I found the option to display the .idea folder in the project tool window, there's a dropdown which I changed from `Project` to `Project Files`.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

For `.idea`  there is dedicated registry setting for it as well (it is enabled by default for me, in PhpStorm at very least)

1. `Help | Find Action...` and look for `registry` (or via `Maintenance`  `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+/` on Windows using Default keymap)
2. Once inside -- look for `projectView.hide.dot.idea` entry
3. Adjust accordingly (before leaving window -- ensure that new value is accepted properly -- e.g. focus another entry)

Took [from](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206248969-Hide-idea-folder-from-the-Project-Explorer-view?page=1#community_comment_115000006310)

### Update since Jun 16, 2020:

You need to restart your IDE after applying changes in Registry. Thanks to @DavidPauli!

Comment: Finally an answer other than "It's hidden for a reason"! Cheers

Comment: Important: You need to restart after that.

Comment: IDE restart is not required. You can simply do right-click in the project view and then `Reload from Disk` in the context menu. P.S: as I remember, earlier it was affected even without reload, but I can be wrong because it is so long ago when I enabled that option

Comment: Thanks! Solved it for me after switching to PhpStorm 2021.1. I needed to restart the IDE. `Reload from Disk` was not sufficient (tried it twice).

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution instead of telling why.

Comment: This setting must also be unchecked in PyCharm Professional, 2021.1.2, to show .ideia folder. Probably in other IDEs JetBrains that this folder is hidden by default is all about that setting.

Comment: I had to restart the IDE too. Reload from Disk was not sufficient.

Comment: On Mac with PhpStorm 2023.1 i managed it on this way: Help > Edit Custom VM Options... will open the file PhpStorm.app.vmoptions in editor. In this file added a new line `-DprojectView.hide.dot.idea=false`. And than just restart PhpStorm

Answer (score 1):

As of PyCharm 2022.2.2, this does not appear to work. After trying various ways of unhiding the .idea folder I had hoped this would be it.

- edit:
  While the registry setting did not work, removing the .idea folder from the Settings/Editor/File Types/Ignored Files and Folders did work!

Answer (score 1):

Please just change the representation of "Project" panel to "Project files" as shown on the screenshot:

[image: screenshot].

Answer (score 1):

Tested on latest WebStorm & PhpStorm, and it is as simple as adding the following setting *(highlighted in the screenshot)* `!.idea` to *Editor > File Types*.

[image: show the ".idea"-folder]

And here is the result:

[image]