# How do I get my settings from PyCharm in a file so not to lose them when updating PyCharm or creating a new Project?

Tags: pycharm

It's happened to me that either I update pycharm (and need to completely reinstall it e.g. M1 mac chip update) or I am about to create a new project that is going to share my folders (but not all) with my previous projects. It usually leads me spending a bunch of time re setting pycharm up e.g. resetting passwords, paths to folders for deployment (when pushing to remote on save), etc. This is time consuming and really annoying. Is there some type of `pycharnm.config` file I save somewhere external to pycharm so to not lose it if I uninstall it or copy paste it to the new project to not redo the work?

How do I get my custom settings (especially from deployment stuff) in a modular way in PyCharm?

---

related:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000081744-How-to-save-deployment-configuration-
- related in part with respect to the deployment: [PhpStorm: How to export deployment settings from a project to another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339996/phpstorm-how-to-export-deployment-settings-from-a-project-to-another-one)
- perhaps is in the `.idea` folder but none of the folders under my project have it! [What is the .idea folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049416/what-is-the-idea-folder)

Comment: to find the `.idea` folder follow these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010238/show-idea-folder-in-phpstorm-project-tool-window it should be in the root of the folder that was used to create the project.

Comment: if you later have issues with git and xcode see this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436612/72191 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71026739/1601580

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74722287/how-does-one-share-only-the-deployment-configurations-in-pycharm-across-pych

Answer (score 0):

To save the settings do

```
File | Manage IDE Settings | Export Settings
```

I did not need to import them since I opened the new pycharm and it already new everything.

For the deployment settings save the`.idea` folder of the project (which was at the root of the folder with the folder name of the github repo that created the project, if you can't find the .idea folder see [Show .idea folder in PhpStorm project tool window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010238/show-idea-folder-in-phpstorm-project-tool-window)). Save it somewhere then put it in the `.idea` of the project folder and it should be ready.

For details on m1 chip upgrade see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025787/1601580 but just installing the dmg works and it seems you don't have to do any of the above I said for some strange reason even if you uninstall the prev pycharm version.

---

if you get issue with xcode and git see this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436612/72191 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71026739/1601580

e.g. getting error:

```
xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (no such file)).
```