# What is the step by step instructions to upgrade my PyCharm from intel silicon to M1 Chip?

Tags: pycharm

When I restored from a time machine pycharm was already there but it was the intel pycharm on my m1 mac. I don't want to lose all my project settings and deployment. Also, I don't understand if I have to uninstall the previous pycharm or how to install it once I downloaded the m1 dmg.

Are there unambiguous steps on how to install the m1 mac PyCharm if one already has a intel PyCharm on my new current m1 mac machine (that was restored from a time machine)?

cross: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4417818919954-What-is-the-step-by-step-instructions-to-upgrade-my-PyCharm-from-intel-silicon-to-M1-Chip-

related: [How do I get my settings from PyCharm in a file so not to lose them when updating PyCharm or creating a new Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025335/how-do-i-get-my-settings-from-pycharm-in-a-file-so-not-to-lose-them-when-updatin)

Comment: careful with this, this actually screwed up my ide settings, it seems sharing deployment settings is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are simple (or they worked too well...)

1. uninstall pycharm by removing it from applications
2. download the arch m1 chip dmg and download it.

That's all.

Although I did save the setting by going to

```
File | Manage IDE Settings | Export Settings
```

I did not need to import them since I opened the new pycharm and it already new everything. Also even though I saved the `.idea` folder of my previous project (which was at the root of the folder with the folder name of the github repo that created the project, if you can't find the .idea folder see [Show .idea folder in PhpStorm project tool window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010238/show-idea-folder-in-phpstorm-project-tool-window)) I didn't end up needed it. Creepy but I guess thats fine.

---

If you get the following error

```
xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (no such file)).
```

do the following (source):

What I suggest is to uninstall the command line tools (CLT) and re-install them the official way ([source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436612/72191)).

So do ([source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436612/72191)):

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

check it uninstalled, you should get an output as follows:

```
xcode-select -p
```

output

```
xcode-select: error: unable to get active developer directory, use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to set one (or see `man xcode-select`)
```

then install the command line tools (CLT) again:

```
xcode-select --install
```

then agree to it and it should download after a couple of minutes. The download should take some time. For me ~13mins.

After that your issues with PyCharm, git, brew and likely other tools will be resolved.

Comment: careful with this, this actually screwed up my ide settings, it seems sharing deployment settings is not easy.